# Best way to separate logic in sailsjs (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, io.js

My application structure consist of few parts. Public API, Admin API, Admin Console (GUI), Private API, Auth API (oauth2, local, socials), etc. They kinda different each to other, but using the same models. Some routes going to have high number of requests per second and couldn't be cached.

I'm interesting in best practices to split everything properly. I'm also opened to another frameworks or even io.js.

Right now I got 3 variants:

1. Create separate apps.
2. Group controllers by folders, and find a way to group routes.
3. Create another instance of sails app and run it into another process (So I can have all controllers, models, but how should I organize subapp structure using this way?)

Answer (score 0):

I think most answers will be opinionated, but putting controllers into subfolders is the easiest way to share models. (easiest but not only)

And you can easily run policies based on those subfolders as well.

However you really need to flesh out more aspects of your question and think about if there will be more shared (like templates or assets) than different or if differences would prohibit a shared app. Will they all use sessions or will they even use the same sessions.

In the end, based on your limited question, sails can do what you want.